# Sidebar Nav is overlapping footer

Tags: jquery, css, overlapping

My sidebar nav is overlapping the footer, how can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: `overflow` ? `z-index` ? `position` ? How should we know what is wrong without even seeing the css ?

Comment: #myScrollspy{
 width:225px;
 font-family: 'GillSans';
 font-size:14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding:25px 25px 15px 25px;
 z-index:12;
 color:#702813;
    border: 2px solid #702813;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    #myScrollspy //sidebar element{
    width:225px;
    font-family: 'GillSans';
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:25px 25px 15px 25px;
    z-index:12;
    color:#702813;
    border: 2px solid #702813;
}

footer{

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whenever someone asks you for some code or clarification, please **edit your original question** instead of adding an answer. That will make this page more readable to others who find it and those who want to answer your question. Thank you!